# flutter has exited unexpectedly: "Invalid argument (URI scheme not allowed)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

**I am building flutter web app but when running its throwing this error:**

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "Invalid argument (URI scheme not allowed):
"file:///home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/example_web/lib/services/networking.dart"".
A crash report has been written to /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/example_web/flutter_07.log.

**Here is Code which error is referring to.**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:core';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class NetworkHelper {
  final String url;

  NetworkHelper({this.url});

  Future<dynamic> getResponseData() async {
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return jsonDecode(response.body);
      } else {
        return response.statusCode;
      }
    } catch (e) {
        print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

**Crash report**

````
Flutter crash report.
Please report a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

## command

flutter run -d chrome

## exception

ArgumentError: Invalid argument (URI scheme not allowed): "file:///home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/example_web/lib/services/networking.dart"

```
#0      DartUri._recordAbsoluteUri (package:dwds/src/utilities/dart_uri.dart:86:7)
#1      DartUri.recordAbsoluteUris (package:dwds/src/utilities/dart_uri.dart:60:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AppInspector._initialize (package:dwds/src/debugging/inspector.dart:88:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      AppInspector.initialize (package:dwds/src/debugging/inspector.dart:152:24)
#4      ChromeProxyService.createIsolate (package:dwds/src/services/chrome_proxy_service.dart:188:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      ChromeProxyService.create (package:dwds/src/services/chrome_proxy_service.dart:155:23)
#6      DebugService.start (package:dwds/src/services/debug_service.dart:140:55)
#7      DevHandler._startLocalDebugService (package:dwds/src/handlers/dev_handler.dart:180:25)
#8      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
#9      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
#10     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
#11     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
#12     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
#13     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
#14     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
#15     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#16     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#17     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
#18     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
#19     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#20     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#21     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#22     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

## flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.20.0, on Linux, locale en_IN)
    • Flutter version 1.20.0 at /home/sarbjyot/flutter
    • Framework revision 916c3ac648 (11 days ago), 2020-08-01 09:01:12 -0700
    • Engine revision d6ee1499c2
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-21.10.beta)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/sarbjyot/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /home/sarbjyot/android-studio-ide-183.5522156-linux/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[!] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /home/sarbjyot/Downloads/android-studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /home/sarbjyot/android-studio-ide-183.5522156-linux/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.9.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Web Server (web) • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome (web)     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 80.0.3987.162

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```
````

Thanks

Comment: So what is the actual value of your variable `url`?

Comment: Actually this is the class I am using to call rest API services but the value is not that important because the error is at compile time  sorry for not sharing value because its a confidential URL cant post it publicly

Comment: Oh, you are right. I guess it's best to follow the instructions and "report a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues" then. Make sure you fill out their template correctly and provide them with a [mcve], because the last person to report the issue [did not](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59924) and it was closed.